# How to prevent all users of a domain network from accessing my shared folders

Tags: domain

- first I have a home network at my house which my laptop is one device on it ,  to overcome sharing problems I gave full control to Everyone group at security tab of the folder,  then at Advanced sharing i have added Everyone group to share permissions and give it a full control,  so now all devices can acces my folder with no password or user name.
- Now at my company they added my private laptop to the domain network to be able to share my company printers and access shared folders at the network.
- The problem is every one now can access my folders at the domain network,  i have opened Advanced sharing settings at my windiws 10 pro,  and turned off file and printer sharing at Domain and  Guest/public networks ,  and checked turn off public folder sharing (people logged on to this computer can still access these folders) option,  but still any one can access my shared folders.
- What i want to be able to,  is sharing every thing with every user at my home network wifi connection, and nothing at my domain network wifi connection,  without toggling share this folder on and of every time

Answer (score 1):

You need to change the permissions on your share from everyone to local users or a local usergroup.

Depending on how easy you want your files to be accessed by others at home, different solutions are possible.

The easiest solution to implement is this:

Use a local account on your laptop and only give that user access to the share. Security settings should remain everyone so you don't have any side-effects locally, but sharing should be set to your local user.

Any family member who wants to access the share will be given a login prompt. If they use your username and password, they can then access the share.

Alternatively, you can create identical users on your laptop where each user has the same username and password as your family member uses to work on their device.

Create a usergroup and add all the local users into that group, then add this group to each share.

Because the username and password are the same, they will automatically be able to access the share without having to enter a password. If they don't have a matching username/password, or they changed their password on their device, they will now get a login prompt with the ability to still login using their old password until you change it on your end to match theirs again.

Answer (score -1):

If your computer is joined to the domain you can grant "deny" read permissions to domain users in the security tab of your shared folder, since specific deny is stronger than allow it should work but I never tested this when "everyone" has full control enable.

Comment: This is a bad idea. This will basically cause him to loose access to the files himself.

Comment: He can always go back to log into the computer with a non domain user and still have access to his file.

Comment: Sure... Come up with a solution, then think of a work-around for the bad side-effects. No. A proper answer would change the shares on his laptop to use his own user and use those  to access the share from other locations on his private network.

Answer (score -1):

first and foremost, always remember that "Deny" will always take precedence whether you're setting "Deny" on NTFS permission or on the GPO. I'll assume that this is just a single shared folder with lots of sub-folders inside, what you want to do with the parent folder is to remove "Everyone" and just add "Domain Users" or any sec group you've created on your domain which contains the domain users that you want to have specific access to the shared folder/s. What will happen is that only those users on that sec-group that you've added with R/W access can have full access to it.

Comment: This is a bad idea. Because he is a member of the domain too, he will deny rights for his own user.

Comment: Yup, that's why I suggested to add domain users or any secgroup which his user/ad account belongs to on the ntfs permission :)

Comment: Its quite likely he has no way to see which users are in which usergroup because he's quite likely not a domain admin, otherwise he would not have asked this question in the first place.